# Error in Jboss Server Using JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss

Im trying to execute my JSF programe but in JBoss server it shows this exception

```
09:40:12,412 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloWorld" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloWorld: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
09:40:12,418 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
```

this is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

You should delete all the files from the deployment folder in JBoss, try to do this, it will help you.